# how do you pause and at a later time resume a workflow from nodejs

Tags: google-workflows

Some of my workflows need to spawn new workflows, some depending on user interaction. How could I pause a workflow and later resume it when the user has provided the information it needs

Answer (score 0):

use tool like iterm, you can spin new environment and let some process running in the background.

Comment: do you have a url for iterm. I cannot find any references that could apply to my needs. thx

Comment: This has nothing to do with google-workflows or nodejs for that matter